# Continuous redirect loop

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to create a URI alias for mypage.php named "mypage". Any requests made to the mypage.php should be redirected to the alias.

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
# Mapped aliases
RewriteRule ^mypage$ /mypage.php [L] # <---- Performs a 301, but shouldn't

# Redirects
RewriteRule ^mypage.php$ /mypage [L,R=301]
```

The result is a continuous redirect loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Mapped aliases
RewriteRule ^mypage$ /mypage.php?redirect=off [L]

# Redirects
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !redirect=off
RewriteRule ^mypage.php$ /mypage [L,R=301]
```